# How to pin a label / UIView to a node in ARKit

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, arkit

I’d like to have a UILabel stay on top of a node in ARKit, similar to the dimensions labels in iOS 12’s Measure app. 
I’ve tried adding the label as a plane node and using a billboard constraint, but then the text gets smaller as you move away, which isn’t ideal. 
At WWDC, they referred to this as Screen Space, but didn’t say how to achieve it.

Thanks in advance! [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've come up with the following solution to make it work.

First, I create the UILabel and add it as a subview. Next, I convert the position of the node I want to follow to screen coordinates in `renderer(_: updateAtTime:)`. Now the label follows the node correctly and stays fixed in scale. However, the label stays horizontal to the screen, which looks weird. To make it stay horizontal to the world, I rotate the label according to the ARCamera's yaw (z rotation).

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {

    // Convert the node's position to screen coordinates
    let screenCoordinate = self.sceneView.projectPoint(node.position)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // Move the label 
    label.center = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(screenCoordinate.x), y: CGFloat(screenCoordinate.y))

    // Hide the label if the node is "behind the screen"
    label.isHidden = (screenCoordinate.z > 1)

    // Rotate the label
    if let rotation = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles.z {
        label.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(rotation + Float.pi/2))
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey Leonard where did you get the `node` and `centerVector` from?

Comment: @Cesare The node is the one you want to attach the overlay too. CenterVector  is supposed to be the screenCoordinate, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a SCNText geometry, I've used the following code some months ago:

```
    var txtNote    = SCNText()
    txtNote.string = "Hello AR word!"
    txtNote.font   = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 2)
    txtNote.extrusionDepth = 1.0
    txtNote.containerFrame = CGRect(x: 2.5, y: 0, width: 16, height: 10)
    txtNote.isWrapped      = true
    txtNote.alignmentMode  = kCAAlignmentLeft
    txtNote.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.black.cgColor

    var txtNode = SCNNode(geometry: txtNote)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only creates the text node. My question was about how to make text, or any UIView, stick to a node. When you move back and forth / walk around the scene with Apple's Measure app, the text doesn't change size and always faces the camera.

Comment: SCNText is a geometry with a string property you can change at run time ("Hello AR word!" in the code) and attach to a SCNNode. To make a node follow the camera there is the SCNBillboardConstraint

Comment: I already described why using a billboard constraint is not the right solution in my original question